# TabControl resizes as window resizes, how to stop auto resizing

Tags: wpf, resize, tabcontrol

My tab content resizes automatically as I resize the window. But I dont want the content to resize when I resize the window. Because of which my TabItem.Content gets wrapped. How do I stop this textwrapping inside the TabControl?

```
<Window x:Class="Editor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Title="Pattern Editor" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor"           
    Height="629.875" Width="910">
    <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">            
        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DockPanel>
                 <Label Name="Formatter" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Background="LightGray"/>
                 <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="EditorTabcontrol" FontFamily="Lucida Console" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">                   
                </TabControl>
            </DockPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Part of the code behind the XAML:

```
RichTextBox mcRTB = new RichTextBox();
rtbList.Add(mcRTB);
mcRTB.SelectionChanged += mcRTB_SelectionChanged;
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tabItemList.Add(tab);

try
{
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);

        mcRTB.Document = document;
}
mcRTB.TextChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventHandler(SegFileDataContentChanged);                       
tab.Header = ExtractFileName(filePath);
tab.Content = mcRTB;
tab.Focus();
tab.DataContext = segFile;
ProgressBar.DataContext = segFile;
```

Comment: I meant the text content inside the tab item, I edited the question as well.

Comment: You still have not shown the text content that get wrapped.  Why would you not post the control that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Edited the question to show part of the code behind XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can't

[RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Text always wraps in a RichTextBox.

Comment: can I use textbox instead of richtextbox? Will TextBox be able handle huge files, I only deal with plaintext in richtextbox.

Comment: Did you try?  Did you check if TextBox has a TextWrap property?  Show some effort.